# NotFoundHttpException No query results for model [App\Article]

Tags: laravel

I'm having a strange problem. For some reason, I am getting the following error when I try to go to this route: `article/create`. The complete error is this:

```
(2/2) NotFoundHttpException
No query results for model [App\Article].
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/article/create','ArticlesController@create');
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('articles.create');
}
```

All standard things, I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have a `GET` route for `/article/{id}` too?

Comment: @ceejayoz No, not yet.

Comment: I have added it now, and still the same.

Comment: It *really* sounds like you're hitting some other route. Can you show us the output of `php artisan route:list` in the question?

Comment: This should not generate a model not found exception, because you are not working with a model. Could you post the full exception, maybe it is thrown in a middleware are something else.

Comment: Can you post your view as well?

Answer (score 1):

The exception `NotFoundHttpException` means that the route you are trying to access is not registered within your `routes/web.php`file.

You have a registered route as

```
Route::get('/article/create','ArticlesController@create');
```

You might be accessing this route from within your blade file on a form submission. The possible reason is that you might be using `method=POST`on your form while the route registered is `GET`which is causing the problem.

If this is the reason one solution is to register your route as `POST`

```
Route::post('/article/create','ArticlesController@create');
```

Comment: It is not a normal httpNotFound but a model is not found. Also registering it as a post is for sure not going to work(Unless it is after a form post) because it is just a view.

Comment: This seem to be not be the correct approach as there is somewhere a Article can not be found in a query based on the error message